# An easy explanation of Tree-vs-Aversary Game

Tags: complexity-theory

I've been reading on the Tree-vs-Aversary game in the example of proving the lower bound of a Decision Tree in the context of Resolution Refutation Proof Complexity.
While I understand how the Adversary game can be used in proving the lower bound of the depth of the tree, I have problems visualising the Tree-vs-Adversary game.

**Rules for the game:**
In each round:

- Tree queries for variable $x_{i}$
- Adversary can either: a) choose value for $x_{i}$ b) let the tree choose the value but in return obtains a point

Game ends when the Tree solves the problem.

**Lemma:**
If there exist an adversary that can score $\geq r$ points then size of Decision Tree $\geq 2^{r}$

**Question:**
Is there a simple function and a strategy you can provide to more easily visualise it?

Comment: No examples were given in class? No exercises?

Comment: Hi, we were given the Pigeon-hole principle but the brief explanation got me confused. I was hoping $OR_{n}$ or $AND_{n}$ could be given as points of explanation

Comment: This method is useless for these functions. Try Majority instead for a (slightly) more interesting example.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks! Another note, in the PH example mentioned in the previous comment I have problems understanding examples of letting the tree decide only one bite..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple but somewhat interesting example: the equality function on $n+n$ bits. This function accepts two input binary strings of length $n$, and returns whether they are equal.

Call the two inputs $x$ and $y$. The adversary's algorithm is as follows. When $x_i$ is queried, if $y_i$ is unknown, then we let the tree decide, and otherwise, we return $1-y_i$; and similarly when $y_i$ is queried. It is not hard to check that the value of the function remains unknown until all inputs have been queried, at which point the adversary has scored precisely $n$ points.